# Implementing Tagless Final Encoding in F# with SRTP

Tags: f#, dsl, tagless-final, f#+, fsharp-typeclasses

I'd like to transform my F# [OOP version](https://github.com/giuliohome/TaglessFinal) of Tagless Final into a typical FP approach and I'm thinking to use [Statically Resolved Type Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/generics/statically-resolved-type-parameters) of [Type Classes from OO](http://www.fssnip.net/7Ts/title/F-SRTP-of-Type-Classes-from-OO-Perspective).

What I've done is

```
open System
open FSharpPlus

type UserName = string
type DataResult<'t> = DataResult of 't with
    static member Map ( x:DataResult<'t>  , f) =
        match x with 
        | DataResult t -> DataResult (f t)
```

creating the SRTP I need

```
type Cache = 
    static member inline getOfCache cacheImpl data =
        ( ^T : (member getFromCache : 't -> DataResult<'t> option) (cacheImpl, data))
    static member inline storeOfCache cacheImpl data =
        ( ^T : (member storeToCache : 't -> unit) (cacheImpl, data))

type DataSource() =
    static member inline getOfSource dataSourceImpl data =
        ( ^T : (member getFromSource : 't -> DataResult<'t>) (dataSourceImpl, data))
    static member inline storeOfSource dataSourceImpl data =
        ( ^T : (member storeToSource : 't -> unit) (dataSourceImpl, data))
```

and their concrete implementations

```
type CacheNotInCache() = 
        member this.getFromCache _ = None
        member this.storeCache _ = () 

type CacheInCache() =
        member this.getFromCache user = monad { 
           return! DataResult user |> Some}
        member this.storeCache _ = () 

type  DataSourceNotInCache() = 
          member this.getFromSource user = monad { 
               return! DataResult user } 

type  DataSourceInCache()  =
          member this.getFromSource _  = 
              raise (NotImplementedException())
```

by which I can define a tagless final DSL

```
let requestData (cacheImpl: ^Cache) (dataSourceImpl: ^DataSource) (userName:UserName) = monad {
    match Cache.getOfCache cacheImpl userName with
    | Some dataResult -> 
            return! map ((+) "cache: ") dataResult
    | None -> 
            return! map ((+) "source: ") (DataSource.getOfSource dataSourceImpl userName) }
```

and that kind of works as follows

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let cacheImpl1 = CacheInCache() 
    let dataSourceImpl1 = DataSourceInCache()
    let cacheImpl2 = CacheNotInCache() 
    let dataSourceImpl2 = DataSourceNotInCache()
    requestData cacheImpl1 dataSourceImpl1 "john" |> printfn "%A"
    //requestData (cacheImpl2 ) dataSourceImpl2 "john" |> printfn "%A"
    0
```

The problem is that I'm getting the warning

> construct causes code to be less generic than indicated by the type
>   annotations

for both `cacheImpl1` and `dataSourceImpl1` and so I can't reuse `requestData` for the other case. 
Is there a way to detour this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the abstraction you're trying to implement, but looking at your code it seems you're missing an `inline` modifier here:

```
let inline requestData (cacheImpl: ^Cache) (dataSourceImpl: ^DataSource) (userName:UserName) = monad {
    match Cache.getOfCache cacheImpl userName with
    | Some dataResult -> 
            return! map ((+) "cache: ") dataResult
    | None -> 
            return! map ((+) "source: ") (DataSource.getOfSource dataSourceImpl userName) }
```

As a side note, you can simplify your map function like this:

```
type DataResult<'t> = DataResult of 't with
    static member Map (DataResult t, f) = DataResult (f t)
```

Comment: Thank you! My final version [here](https://github.com/giuliohome/TaglessFinal/blob/srtp/TypeClasses/Program.fs)

Answer (score 0):

I am familiar with final tagless, but I'm not sure why you would use SRTPs.
Final tagless uses type classes, and these can be emulated with interfaces (see the way scala emulates typeclasses).

The approach is similar to (basically the same) as "object algebra", which can be implemented using standard OO constructs.