# How do I add SRTP constraints on an interface?

Tags: f#

Say I'd like an interface with a member `Write` that accepts a generic type constrained to have an `Id: int` field.

Is this possible in F#?  I've tried this and variations on it but always get the `The code is not sufficiently generic. The type variable... would escape its scope.` error.

Other similar questions suggest using an inline member, but that's not possible on interfaces.

```
type IDatabase<'T when 'T : (member Id: int)> =
    abstract member Save: 'T -> unit
```

Comment: Statically-resolved type parameters work on types and do it at compile-time, hence statically-resolved. Interfaces - types with abstract member functions - where the generics are resolved at run-time. That is static members versus abstract members. They can't be both at the same time. I think you want to create in interface like solution using STRP see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55483735/implementing-tagless-final-encoding-in-f-with-srtp/55484235#55484235

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't know that compile-time vs. run-time difference.  Have to read up and  and experiment some more.  And you're right, there's an XY problem going on... I was able to go back and reorganize code to use HOFs without generics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there any reason why you cannot use normal interface constraints that are supported by the .NET runtime?

```
type IEntity = 
  abstract Id : int

type IDatabase<'T when 'T :> IEntity> =
  abstract member Save: 'T -> unit
```

There are two main differences between using SRTPs and interfaces:

- Interface constraints are directly supported by the .NET runtime and F# leverages that, so the constraints compile to .NET constraints. With SRTPs, the constraints have to be satisfied at compile-time, which imposes various restrictions.
- If you introduce an interface, you have to be able to modify all classes that you want to be able to handle (to implement the interface). With SRTPs, you can rely on "duck typing" and a member that already happens to exist for all classes you care about.

If the second condition is not too restrictive for you (i.e., you control all the classes), then interfaces are an easier option.

Comment: Thanks.  No reason I couldn't use interfaces, other than my poor understanding of interfaces vs. SRTPs in the first place!

Comment: @capitalistcuttle I added some clarification regarding the differences to the answer!